# How to tell typescript the correct indexed key

Tags: typescript

```js
    type Type = {
      aa: string;
      bb: number;
    };
    
    const keys = ['aa', 'bb'] as (keyof Type)[];
    const target = {} as {
      [Key in keyof Type]: Type[Key];
    };
    
    const source: Type = {
      aa: 'aa',
      bb: 123
    };
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      const s = source[key]; //string | number
      const t = target[key]; //string | number
      /**
       * Error: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
       * Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
       */
      target[key] = source[key];
    });
```

As the code show above `target[key] = source[key];` is not allowed, here is my reason about:

`source[key]` is `string | number` and `target[key]` is also `string | number`, so the assignment is not allowed, but the compiler ignore the fact that `key` is actually the **same one**, i.e. if `source[key]` is `string`, `target[key]` **must be** string as well,

How do I tell the typescript about the constraint, it seem that I should put some generic type param somewhere, but no idea what exactly I should do

Comment: You can't do this with unions; the compiler does not track the correlation between the type of `target[key]` and `source[key]` see [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). The recommended fix is indeed to use generics, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6g2w). Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz your solution is exactly I need, actually my initial try is `keys.forEach(<K >(key: K)=>{...}`  expecting ts bind `K` with `keyof Type` automatically, but it do not work out. So, the correct is to `extends` with `keyof Type` explictly... Thanks a lot

Comment: @jcalz it is actually pretty ugly putting `K extends keyof Type` in my perspective, the type is already inferred from the array! Why should declare it again with something already clear just to make it a variable?

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance.  As for your next comment, TypeScript doesn't *infer* generic constraints, so `<K>(key: K) =>` has an unconstrained `K`.  So `<K extends keyof Type>(key: K) =>` might be ugly, but it is also necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, the following doesn't work

```
keys.forEach(key =>
  target[key] = source[key] // error! string | number not assignable to never
);
```

because the compiler is not keeping track of the correlation between the [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `target[key]` and `source[key]`.  They are both `string | number`, but the compiler does not realize that they will either both be `string` or both be `number`.  It does not notice that the identity of `key` ties the two sides of the assignment together.

Since indexed access types were made more strict in TypeScript 3.5, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), the compiler will only allow assignments like `target[key] = source[key]` for union-typed `key` if every possible assignment would succeed, by treating the assignment target as the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the property types.  That is, `target[key]` would only accept a value of type `string & number` (a.k.a. the impossible [`never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type)) instead of `string | number`.

---

Lack of direct support for correlated unions is reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).
And the recommended fix, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), is to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  Essentially, when `key` is generic and when `target` and `source` have the same type, then the compiler *will* allow `target[key] = source[key]` (even though this is unsound, as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559) in microsoft/TypeScript#30769).

So to fix your example, we should make the `forEach()` callback a generic function, like this:

```
keys.forEach(<K extends keyof Type>(key: K) => {
  target[key] = source[key]; // okay
});
```

Now `key` is of generic type `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof Type`.  Both sides of the assignment are of identical generic type `Type[K]`, and the compiler allows this.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BQUoENMC4oGdgAnASwDsBzAbnSgCM68yBXAWzoiJoF8bUBjAPZlCUANYQQ+KEgDaAcmzyANFHkN5AXSzShI4DT2jgmIhQjAZKbjtjw+Ry-kHMi-CHjiQraDNjyKmCq0DHgAjABMAMyovKioElIAdABmgkQAopj8ABYAFIkyAHy0JmYWsonaSM6u7pWS2gD0TVCcROkAhATE5BRQAD5QLOycw4KWmPj4JBRkmHQANtDAgsMQAG6cqACUfIn4qelZuXkAPADSbQAewBBkACbSiYIpdpBFBZJ4FzvFKKVTOZgA0QNUCC43BBQZoqFAWlBBGJMCBYnsgA)